# How to print localStorage array in html for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have an array in my localStorage which contains ["January","Febuary"]
I want it to be displayed in HTML preferably like this:

```
Month
January
Febuary
```

So I've tried this code:

```
function show(){
    for(let i = 0;i < localStorage.length;i++){
        var date = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("date"));
        }
    for(var b = 0; b < nameLength; b++){
        document.getElementById('storageOut').innerHTML = date[b];
        console.log(date[b]);   
    }   
}
```

My code above does work however, the line `"document.getElementById('storageOut').innerHTML = date[b];"`only prints out the last data in the array, but when i check the console it prints out both.

Comment: `document.getElementById('storageOut').innerHTML += date[b];`?

Comment: you are over-writing contents of innerHTML. To make it work use the += operator rather than = operator after innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You create the variable `date` in the first for-loop and assign it to one value each iteration. Easiest way would probably be to do it in a single for-loop instead:

```
function show(){
  for(let i = 0;i < localStorage.length;i++){
    var date = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("date"));
    document.getElementById('storageOut').innerHTML = date;
  }
}
```

Although, if you want all the dates, you should probably append it to the innerHtml:

```
...innerHTML += date;
```

Or rather:

```
...innerText += date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your contents are stored in local storage key named **data**. Try the following.

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))
data.forEach(item => {
    document.getElementById('storageOut').innerHTML += item
})
```